# how to get the last work date in group

Tags: sql

I have query like this

```
SELECT        
  A.JBCo, A.Invoice, MAX(B.JCDate) AS LastWorkedDay, C.Description
FROM            
  C 
INNER JOIN A ON 
  C.JBCo = A.JBCo AND 
  C.BillMonth = A.BillMonth AND 
  C.BillNumber =  A.BillNumber 
INNER JOIN B ON 
  C.JBCo = B.JBCo AND 
  C.BillMonth = B.BillMonth AND 
  C.BillNumber = B.BillNumber AND 
  C.Line = B.Line
GROUP BY 
  A.Invoice, A.JBCo, C.Description
HAVING        
  (A.JBCo = 12) AND 
  (A.Invoice LIKE '%1000223%')
```

which get the result like

```
Co          invoice             Lastworkdate        description
12         1000223              2012-12-9             Labor
12         1000223              2012-12-7             Equipment
12         1000223              2012-12-2              Material
```

I need a query to result like 
when there is 'Labor', then use the lastWorkedDate in Labor, if there is no labor in the Invoice then use the lasted date. So the final result will only be one line for each invoice, in this case will be (There is no need to show the Description). I try to use case when statement but i can not get it right. please help. Thanks

```
12     1000223      2012-12-09
```

Comment: What is the lasted date?

Comment: just the max date for that invoice. When the invoice has Labor use the max date in Labor group otherwise just use the max data for that invoice regardless the Description

Comment: Do you want a single line as output, as you showed at the bottom of your question? (i.e. without the 'Description' in the output)?

Comment: yes i only need one single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a case statement to your query, you can get the MaxDate of only the LaborDates. The case expression would look like this:

```
MAX(case when C.Description = 'Labor' then B.JCDate else null end) AS LastLaborDay
```

If you add that and run it, you will now have two columns. One has the Max date, the other has the max labor date... with null where it is non-labor.

You can now use this query result as a nested table. You group by Invoice to reduce to a single row. You also find the max of your two date columns. If there was no labor, that max will be null. So, use COALESCE() to select the first non-null.

It will look something like this:

```
select JBCO, invoice, max(LastLaborDay), max(LastWorkedDay), coalesce(max(LastLaborDay), max(LastWorkedDay))
from 
(
SELECT        
  A.JBCo, A.Invoice, MAX(B.JCDate) AS LastWorkedDay, 
  MAX(case when C.Description = 'Labor' then B.JCDate else null end) AS LastLaborDay, 
  C.Description
FROM            
  C 
INNER JOIN A ON 
  C.JBCo = A.JBCo AND 
  C.BillMonth = A.BillMonth AND 
  C.BillNumber =  A.BillNumber 
INNER JOIN B ON 
  C.JBCo = B.JBCo AND 
  C.BillMonth = B.BillMonth AND 
  C.BillNumber = B.BillNumber AND 
  C.Line = B.Line
GROUP BY 
  A.Invoice, A.JBCo, C.Description
HAVING        
  (A.JBCo = 12) AND 
  (A.Invoice LIKE '%1000223%')
) TBL1
```

Take a look [at this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7fdc/30), and tweak it if you need to.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same way by using Union all and get two seperated date then combine them together, Yours are better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT        
  A.JBCo, A.Invoice, 
CASE WHEN description="Labor" THEN MAX(B.JCDate) ELSE MAX(B.JCDate) END AS LastWorkedDay, 
  C.Description
FROM            
  C 
INNER JOIN A ON 
  C.JBCo = A.JBCo AND 
  C.BillMonth = A.BillMonth AND 
  C.BillNumber =  A.BillNumber 
INNER JOIN B ON 
  C.JBCo = B.JBCo AND 
  C.BillMonth = B.BillMonth AND 
  C.BillNumber = B.BillNumber AND 
  C.Line = B.Line
GROUP BY 
  A.Invoice
HAVING        
  (A.JBCo = 12) AND 
  (A.Invoice LIKE '%1000223%')
```

Comment: thanks.but it give me the same result since it still group by Description

Comment: Do you need a single line in the result instead of three?